# Dropdown unresponsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a dropdown using this component
https://github.com/fraserxu/react-dropdown

I am calling it like this:

```
<Dropdown options={monthOptions} onChange={this.changeMonth} value={defaultMonth} placeholder="Select Month" />
```

Using this data:

```
export const monthOptions = [
  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
  "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

export const defaultMonth = "January";
```

And this method:

```
  changeMonth: function(option) {
      this.setState({month: option});
  },
```

However, when I display the component in the browser, it is unresponsive. It doesn't show any options:

[image]

There is no message printed in the console.

Comment: Is your component created by `React.createClass` or is it an ES6 class?

Comment: It is inside a component which is created using `React.createClass`.